# How do I programmatically add an IP address to the blocked list in Windows Server 2003?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server-2003, firewall

Following on from the general answers in this question:

[Blocking access to site by banned IP addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954012/blocking-access-to-site-by-banned-ip-addresses)

and working on a C# ASP.NET MVC stack, how would I programmatically add IP addresses to the list of banned IP addresses on a Windows Server 2003 firewall?

The use case is that the log files on the web app record attacks on a web site. From the admin page I want to be able to click a button/link and have that IP address added to the blocked list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you'll want to do is modify the IPSec policies of Windows. I don't want to duplicate answers here, but take a look at the following threads, which should get you what you need:

- [Methods of programatically altering ipsec rules with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609882/methods-of-programatically-altering-ipsec-rules-with-c)
- [Is there a cmdlet in PowerShell 2 to handle ipsec changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703205/is-there-a-cmdlet-in-powershell-2-to-handle-ipsec-changes)